# Requirements to Specification Mapping Tools

Tags: ms-word, requirements, specifications

Our team captures user stories in TFS. I use the great tool [TeamSpec](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=teamspec&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://www.teamsystemsolutions.com/teamspec/&ei=VntMT4qlBcipiAeSselS&usg=AFQjCNFADRIVhe4_xW40SCW20ITctgw9UQ&cad=rja) to dump these into a word document for good 'ol fashioned easy reading.

Now, we are at the point where we need to produce a functional specification that describes the software that will be built to support those user stories.

Again, I'd probably like this functional spec in word ultimately - as this has to be a readable document that the customer can read and sign off on.

That said, I would really love to have a tool that helps me map user stories to functional requirements, possibly even generating the matrix (in both directions) for easy reference.

What tools are there that might help me? Googling is no help at all. :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what we have decided to do.

There will be a High Level Design, and a Functional Specification document. 
The customer will get both, but the HDD will be written up front, for sign off, agreement and limiting of scope. 
The functional specification will also be signed off on, but incrementally - we will fill in a section as we decide what will be done, and get sign off.

The HDD will have User stories in it, each user story is a ticket in TFS, synched via teamspec.
The Func Spec will have tasks in it, which are user stories broken down into features/requirments. Teamspec again used to populate this stuff in the func spec.

So the only thing left is showing a matrix - I will use the ability of TFS to pop out a .xls file - if it shows the user story -> task breakdown, that gives me the matrix we need.

So that's it really.

It solves the issue of HDD, Func spec, mapping of requirements and items between the two, while still recording it in TFS for access via developers.